# Mongo: count total documents across all groups

Tags: mongodb

I'm aware of how to count documents *within* each group:

```
Model.aggregate([
        { $limit: 10 },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "$type",
                docs: { $push: "$$ROOT" },
                nDocs: { $sum: 1 },
            },
        },
```

This will return an array of objects in which `nDocs` is the count of `docs` in *each* group. Is there a way to count documents at the top level *across all groups*? Eg if there were three groups, each with `nDocs` of 2, how can I get a total count of 6?

Edit:

```
[
  {
    total: 5,
    results: {
      { 
        _id: 'fruits', 
        docs: [ [Object] ], 
        nDocs: 1 
      },
      {
        _id: 'vegetables',
        docs: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
        nDocs: 4
      }
    },
  }
]
```

Comment: Could you show the output as json? I mean where do you want that key to be added in the list because I don't think adding key to each 3 documents will make any sense!!

Comment: @Ashh see edited. Do you mean a top-level key (`total`) that sums the `nDocs` of the `fruits` and `vegetables` groups would not make sense?

Comment: You can add on more `$group` stage. `{
 $group: {
  _id: null,
  results: { $push: "$$ROOT" },
  total: { $sum: "$nDocs" }
 }
}`

Comment: Mind elaborating? Getting `MongoError: The argument to $size must be an array, but was of type: missing` but may be misunderstanding you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one more `$group` stage to get the total documents count and use `$push` to get all the documents inside single array(results)

```
{
    $group: {
        _id: null,
        results: { $push: "$$ROOT" },
        total: { $sum: "$nDocs" }
    }
}
```